# How do I delete my number from iMessage on send and receive from my iMac?

Tags: macos, messages

When I go to settings, iMessage does not show up under anything and I cannot access iMessage settings straight from the iMessage icon.

Comment: Could you upload a screen shot of what you are seeking to do? The messages app works with the iMessage service and an iCloud account so it's not clear what settings or preference you need assistance with.

Comment: I know you can do it on iOS. Just open Messages under the Settings app. Not sure if it's possible on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Message app first before doing the following:

To remove your phone number from the Messages app in OSX, you need to change your Messages preferences: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

In the Preferences box, click Accounts, select your iMessage account on the left, and uncheck your phone number on the right.

[image: remove number from Messages app]